# Ionic serve livereload break on code changes

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have some troubles with the livereload `ionic serve --lab` in one of my `ionic` projects. If I do some changes in my code (`.ts`, `.html`, ...) then the livereload stops working with the following error messsage.

### Error message:

```
events.js:183
throw er; // Unhandled ‘error’ event
^

Error: read ECONNRESET
at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
at TCP.onread (net.js:615:25)
```

---

### My config (package.json):

cli packages: (C:\Users\gkastenhofer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.1.2
npm  : 5.8.0
OS   : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

---

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the following outdated package:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
```

This issue can be fixed with the following `npm` commands:

```
npm uninstall --save ws
npm install --save-dev @ionic/app-scripts@latest
```

For further information: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2921